# How to setup Octopus Deploy for a LightSwitch HTML client

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, octopus-deploy, lightswitch-2013

I have a LightSwitch HTML client (Visual Studio 2013) which I like to automate deployment using Octopus, but I'm not sure how to get this working.

Octopus is already set up and working for MVC sites, using the Octopack package, but there doesn't seem to be a similar project to add this to for LightSwitch. I've tried the HTMLClient project but the package doesn't get created.

Does anyone know if is this possible or have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you releasing your current MVC nuget packages to Octopus through a build server?

The other alternative is to use NuGet.exe which is a command line tool to create packages (Ocotopack is a wrapper around this).

If you're using something like TeamCity then this is wrapped up in the NuGet Pack runner - it just needs a path to the NuSpec file. If you're not using a build server then you may be able to run some post build command to fire up NuGet.exe. Here's the link to the [command line reference for the Pack Command](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Pack_Command)

Also, ensure that you've also got the usual NuSpec definition within your project too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but unfortunately lightswitch doesn't have a csproj file. It has a lsxproj file but this doesn't produce any output.

Comment: Yes, it's using TFS. I've now got something working that's basically doing what you've suggested. If you want to add another answer or edit this one ,I'll happy accept it.